# jquery-1.3.2.js full calendar problem in ie 6 7 & 8

Tags: jquery

Having a problem with the jquery-1.3.2.js file and the fullcalendar plugin with ie 6 - 8 i get Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0; Trident/4.0; GTB6; SLCC1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; Media Center PC 5.0; .NET CLR 3.5.21022; InfoPath.2; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729)
Timestamp: Fri, 10 Jul 2009 22:31:12 UTC

Message: Invalid argument.
Line: 1048
Char: 4
Code: 0
URI: http://localhost:3169/Scripts/jquery/jquery-1.3.1.js

Answer (score 1):

[This link](http://dev.jquery.com/ticket/4420) points to a known issue with IE and using jQuery dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Use this calendar instead.

http://www.dynarch.com/projects/calendar/old/

There is nothing better, and it's free if you can deal with the little question mark in the top left corner.

Comment: I don't want a date picker, the fullcalendar is working in every browser, but ie, ie is displaying a java error, non of the other browsers are though

Comment: I know that url states 1.3.1, but i have tried both 1.3.1 & 1.3.2